# Writing test cases in Haskell for differing types

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, testing

I've made a library that creates "list like" sequences, and of which many Prelude style functions are implemented. I want to write some test cases for this, to ensure my library is producing correct output, and I thought the easiest way to do this is write some functions, convert the results to lists and compare them to the Prelude results. Lets say we've got this:

```
import qualified MyLibrary as ML
import qualified Prelude as P
```

For example I may want the following testcase:

```
P.take 5 (P.enumFrom 1) == toList (ML.take 5 (ML.enumFrom 1))
```

Note that `ML.enumFrom` does not output a list, it outputs it's own datatype.

The above works fine, but notice how I'm "repeating myself" *(TM)*. I have to ensure the left and right side are the same otherwise my test case is erroneous.

Is there a nice way to write test cases like this so I don't have to repeat myself?

Comment: I don't think you are really "repeating yourself" when your test is by definition to "repeat itself" in order to compare two mechanisms.

Comment: Ideally all the tests take a parameter which determines which function to use so I could just have a `doTest` function which is like `doTest test = test True == toList (test False)` or something like that, but I haven't found a way to do this without the typechecker hating me.

Comment: @Clinton: I think that without instantiating a common `class` or possibly using template haskell (which I have no experience with) you cannot achieve that

Answer (score 1):

The first problem that `P.take` and `ML.take`, etc., only look similar – in fact they are totally unrelated functions and the compiler doesn't know anything about their common behaviour. So, as @jd823592 proposed, we need to group them with a typeclass (I used a simple `newtype` wrapper so the example would be compilable):

```
import Prelude hiding (take, enumFrom)
import qualified Prelude as P (take, enumFrom)

newtype MySeq a = MySeq [a]

class Sequence s where
    take :: Int -> s a -> s a
    enumFrom :: Enum a => a -> s a
    toList :: s a -> [a]

instance Sequence MySeq where
    take n (MySeq xs) = MySeq (P.take n xs)
    enumFrom n = MySeq (P.enumFrom n)
    toList (MySeq xs) = xs

instance Sequence [] where
    take = P.take
    enumFrom = P.enumFrom
    toList = id
```

Then we'll try to define some tests using now-unified functions from the class definition. They may just generate a `Sequence` of any type, and we'll then force them to produce explicit types.

```
test1 = doTest (take 5 $ enumFrom 1) -- the part in brackets is polymorphic

doTest :: (Eq a, Sequence s) => s a -> Bool
doTest test = ???
```

Now the second problem is that we pass a polymorphic function as a parameter and then need to instantiate it with different type parameters (`[a]` and `MySeq a` in this case). In standard Haskell 2010 it is impossible, but we can exploit the [Rank2 (or RankN) extension](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Polymorphism#Higher_rank_types):

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}

<...>

doTest :: forall a . Eq a => (forall s . Sequence s => s a) -> Bool
doTest test = (test `asTypeOf` dummy1) == toList (test `asTypeOf` dummy2) where
    dummy1 :: Eq a => [a]
    dummy1 = undefined
    dummy2 :: Eq a => MySeq a
    dummy2 = undefined
```

This solution is a bit clumsy, but still works. Please feel free to improve.